# Remove duplicates from left join

Tags: sql, left-join

Table A:

```
MSISDN  A   B   C
990 1   2   3
992 1   2   3
995 1   2   3
993 1   2   3
991 1   2   3
994 1   2   3
```

Table B:

```
990 2   2   3
992 2   2   4
993 1   2   3
994 1   2   3
995 1   6   3
990 1   2   3
991 2   2   3
992 2   2   3
995 1   2   3

select msis1.msisdn,msis1.a,msis2.c from msis1 left join msis2 on msis1.msisdn=msis2.msisdn;

MSISDN  A   C
990 1   3
992 1   4
993 1   3
994 1   3
995 1   3
990 1   3
991 1   3
992 1   3
995 1   3
```

I want to modify the above query not to get duplicate records

Comment: `select DISTINCT ..`

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT DISTINCT`, this will only select rows that are unique.